# How do I import Ekko Lightbox into my Angular 7 Project?

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-4, lightbox

I am trying to use Ekko lightbox in my angular project. I have a component that I want to specifically use it in and I am not sure how to import the proper files into the component.

I installed Ekko via NPM and all the files are listed under in "node_modules/Ekko-lightbox"

The documentation for Ekko is listed here: http://ashleydw.github.io/lightbox/

Here is my Angular Component code. (I have already imported Jquery and added the function code into NgOnInIt)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
declare var $:any;



@Component({
  selector: 'app-graphic-design',
  templateUrl: './graphic-design.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./graphic-design.component.css', '/node_modules/ekko-lightbox/dist/ekko-lightbox.css']
})
export class GraphicDesignComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    $(document).on('click', '[data-toggle="lightbox"]', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $(this).ekkoLightbox();
  });
  }

}
```

I also added the HTML sample code listed in the documentation in my component HTML

```
<a href="https://unsplash.it/1200/768.jpg?image=251" data-toggle="lightbox">
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/600.jpg?image=251" class="img-fluid">
</a>
```

The image pops up, however when I click it nothing happens. It also doesn't seem to be responsive at all.

Here is my angular.json I linked the scripts and css files, but it's still not working

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Inside angular.json, please include lightbox related style and script files. It should work.

```
"styles": [
  "styles.css"
],
"scripts": [],
```

Comment: do I need the pathfile or just the filename?

Comment: you need to define whole path from 'node_modules'

Comment: I added and still doesn't work. Maybe you can try to setup a test angular component to try and replicate it?

Comment: Here is the Angular version of lightbox. you can try integrating this. https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-lightbox